I made a JavaScript daily trigger for a function that updates an innerHTML and it didn't run properly
function triggerDailyUpdate() {
        console.log('the Function worked');
        setInterval(function(){
            const now = new Date();
            if (now.getHours() === 0 && now.getMinutes() === 0) {
                console.log("Conditions detected, regenerating table for the next day");
                predictionsContainer.innerHTML = "";
                setupPredictions();
            }
        }, 60000); 

I made a javascript function where it'll trigger a daily update to a table using an inner HTML. When I checked it on the dev mode from my browser it only run the console.log for "The Function Worked" and the rest of the code didn't properly run. I tried to test it by changing the get hours and minutes value and it still didn't trigger. What went wrong? I just wanted it to trigger the setupPrediction function daily based on the getHours and getMinutes value (which is midnight)

is you page always active? inactive pages are throttled, so you could miss your now.getMinutes() === 0

I haven't deployed it yet so I tried it using live server from VSCode.

What are you really trying to achieve? Or, to put it differently, what does your table contain, and why are you regenerating it? What does regenerating mean in your context? The reason for all these questions - perhaps you're going about this the wrong way, and there's no need to do what you're currently doing (one reason is what @AlexanderNenashev mentions - it's fairly easy to miss your conditions).

Have you really started this and waited until midnight, to see if it triggers? Because it will only do anything exactly at midnight. And even then it's not guaranteed if you're really unlucky and it triggers once at 23:59:59 and then again at 00:01:00.

I did wait for it yesterday, Let me test it again.
